# CSS 3D Transform | Inaccesible Content After Transition

Tags: jquery, css

[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twahlin/e344M/12/) of what I'm trying to do.

jQuery transit and CSS3 3D transitions are being used in order to rotate 2 divs on click. If you take a look at the fiddle, clicking 'rotate' will change the perspective on the div so 'rotate back' is showing. 'rotate back' is not clickable, as there appears to be some funky z-indexing or positioning going on.

HTML

```
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="face face-1"><span class="rotate">rotate</span></div>
  <div class="face face-2"><span class="rotate-back">rotate back</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".rotate").click(function () {
    $(".masthead").transition({
        perspective: '0',
        rotateX: '90deg',
        duration: 250
    });
});
    $(".rotate-back").click(function () {
    $(".masthead").transition({
        perspective: '0',
        rotateX: '-90deg',
        duration: 250
    });
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.masthead {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 22px 22px 0;
}
.masthead .face {
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.masthead .face-1 {
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(22px);
}
.masthead .face-2 {
    background: aqua;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(22px);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should know that creating 3D transformations creates different z-index stack.

Comment: Thanks @drinchev: It's odd - if the element 'face-2' is inspected after rotation, it almost seems to go below it's parent. Is there a way to alleviate this?

Comment: I don't know why it's happening, but it goes much better if you rotate to 89 deg instead of 90.

Comment: Hmmm, that is odd. The content still seems accessible at 89.

Answer (score 0):

The red is coming over blue and vice-versa. Use pointer-events to allow the click to reach your target element.

```
  $('.face-1').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  $('.face-2').css('pointer-events', '');
```

Is this what you had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/e344M/14/

Comment: That fiddle seems to exhibit the same issue

Comment: Also chrome, Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: There is a problem with the text, it hides after the rotated layer, but clicks are working. Try this and please let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/e344M/15/

Comment: As far as I can tell the clicks are the issue: I added a `console.log("Click");` at the very beginning of both event handlers. Only the first one fires.